# ¿Cómo puedo saber si un Queryset de Django está vacío?

Tags: django, base-de-datos

Necesito verificar si un Queryset que obtengo en django está vacío por ejemplo:
`persona = Persona.objects.get(ci="12345678901")`
me haría falta saber si `persona` contiene algun valor y no se como hacerlo, el código esta en `views.py`

Answer (score 6):

Cuando usas `get()` **NO** obtienes un QuerySet, si no un objeto directamente, pero tienes aun así dos opciones:

La primera con el `get()`:

```
try:
   persona = Persona.objects.get(ci="12345678901")
except Persona.DoesNotExist:
   persona = None
```

De aquí sabes que si persona no es `None`, la obtuviste, de lo contrario no existe.

Por un QuerySet:

```
 persona = Persona.objects.filter(ci="12345678901").exists()
```

Que retorna `True` si encontró a alguien con esa característica o `False` si no lo encontró

Answer (score 1):

En ese caso en particular `Persona.objects.get(ci="12345678901")` **NO** retorna un QuerySet sino un objeto de la clase `Persona`. Si necesitas seguir usando el metodo `.get()` del ORM podrías hacerlo de esta forma:

```
try:
    persona = Persona.objects.get(ci="12345678901")
except Persona.DoesNotExist:
    # entrará aqui cuando no exista ningun elemento
    # que coincida con la busqueda
    pass
except Persona.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    # entrará aqui cuando se haya encontrado más de un
    # objeto que coincida
    pass
```

Si lo que necesitas es sólo saber si existe o no, y el campo `ci` que usas para filtrar es único o en su defecto se puede confiar en él, puedes usar el método `.filter()` del ORM:

```
persona = Persona.objects.filter(ci="12345678901")  # Esto si retorna un QuerySet
persona.exists()  # Devuelve True si hay elementos en el resultado False de lo contrario
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, pondre ambos ejemplos en practica y publicaré el resultado

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un atajo que se llama `get_object_or_404` que funciona muy bien, está es la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404).

Answer (score 1):

un clásico es usar el método `count()` combinado con `filter()`:

```
Persona.objects.filter(ci="12345678901").count() > 0
```

el ORM lo suele traducir en una sentencia que incluye un `SELECT count(ci) FROM ...` que es más eficiente en tiempo de ejecución de la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la siguiente linea.

```
persona = Persona.objects.filter(ci="12345678901").first()
```

En caso de que no encuentre el objeto con ese ci entonces devolverá None

Answer (score -1):

También puedes hacer un simple `if` de la siguiente manera:

```python
if persona:
    print("no esta vacio")
else:
    print("vacio")
    persona=none
```